# Mapping between two different agencies roadway shapefiles of Las Vegas in ArcGIS

Tags: arcmap, shapefile

I have two roadway shapefiles of Vegas. But they do not overlap. One of the file has a certain shift from its exact location. Can anyone help me how can I move the location so that they overlap exactly and I can map those two different shapefiles in ArcMap?

Comment: we need some extra info: coordinate system of each shape file, extent, did you download this files (if yes, from where).

Comment: amount of shift...

Comment: The coordinate system of both the files are same i.e. projected on NAD 1983 UTM zone 11.We didnt download these files but we got from State Agency. The amount of shift between the two is not uniform(but the shift follows a trend) and also the shift is both in easting and northing.

Comment: It is still tough to provide an answer here. If the 'shift is not uniform, but follows a trend' there may be an issue with the stated coordinate system not being the coordinate system used to create the data. Have you tried changing the coordinate system for the data that you suspect has errors to some other common ones for the area (e.g. State Plane, geographic, etc.)?

Comment: Did the shapefiles come with a .prj file? If not, the assumption that both have the same CRS might be wrong. Can you measure the shift of difference for a few remarkable road crossings in metres? And can you underlay the data with Google satellite imagery to see which one is right and which is wrong?

Comment: Yeah I tried changing the coordinate system for the data but the problem is not fixed. I underlayed the data with google imagery, one of the roadway file has a little shift but the other one lies exactly at the right place. I tried measuring the difference, since its not unifrom they vary in locations.